# Swift - throw error if the element doesn't exist in the array

Tags: swift

I've two arrays of int, with 3 elements each.
I'm trying to throw an error if the int number I received with func doesn't exist in the arrays

```
func switch(a: Int, b: Int) throws -> Void {

   if a < 0 || b < 0 || a > arrayA.count || b > arrayB.count {
 
       throw SwitchError.error
}
```

---

I'm trying to use count to do this, but always return the error that numbers don't exist in the array even though they are there... is there another way to achieve this?

```
class SoccerPlayer {                   
    let name: String
    let number: Int
    init(name: String, number: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
    }
}
```

---

```
class Team {
    var nameTeam: String
    var arrayA: [SoccerPlayer] = []
    var arrayB: [SoccerPlayer] = []
    init(nameTeam: String, arrayA: [SoccerPlayer], arrayB: [SoccerPlayer]) {
        self.nameTeam = nameTeam
        self.arrayA = arrayA
        self.arrayB = arrayB
    }
    func switch(a: Int, b: Int) throws -> Void {
        if a < 0 || b < 0 || a > arrayA.count || b > arrayB.count {
            throw SwitchError.error
        } 
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Which number are you testing? a or b? Or both?

Comment: both numbers...

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains?

Comment: so using .contains I can't use my parameter A, or B right? Because they are the ones I want to check if they exist in the array or not

Comment: Honestly, I can’t really tell from your code or your question exactly what you’re trying to do (thus my leaving comments and not an answer). Are you trying to see if arrayA contains a and arrayB contains b?

Comment: That's right! Sorry if it looked confused

Comment: Okay, then again, I’d suggestion `contains`. Such as `!arrayA.contains(a)` if you want it to return true if the array does not contain the value

Comment: You are validating the **indices** rather than checking the values.

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you!! But I'm got an error " Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'yourClass' " 
I forgot to say that my array is of type of my Class... Is there a way to get around this error?

Comment: @vadian so I thought .count would be the right one to use on this occasion, but I can't use it

Comment: @FlavioGrandini no — you can’t compare an Int to a class. It is unclear to the compiler how they would be equal. Can you show your class and explain the relationship to the Int?

Comment: If `arrayA` is `[1, 2, 3]` and `a` is `2` and you want to check if `arrayA` contains `2` then you have to check `arrayA.contains(a)`

Comment: @jnpdx I have a class SoccerPlayer, with name and number
and I have a class Team with nameTeam and the two arrays that are of type SoccerPlayer...

Comment: Seeing code would be much more helpful than a description, but if I understand correctly, you want to check if an array of `SoccerPlayer` contains an item with a certain `number`?

Comment: @jnpdx That's Right!!

Comment: @FlavioGrandini Eu ja tinha adicionado a lógica pra verificar se os jogadores existiam antes de remove-los na sua outra pergunta. Você só precisa adicionar um `} else {` no final do `if {` e throw o erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the additional information from the comments, it looks like you have arrays like this:

```
class SoccerPlayer {
  var name : String
  var number : Int
  //etc
}

var arrayA : [SoccerPlayer] = ...
var arrayB : [SoccerPlayer] = ...
```

Given that setup, if you want to check whether the arrays contains an element where the `number` property is matched, you could do either of these:

```
func check(a: Int, b: Int) throws {
    if a < 0 || b < 0 || !arrayA.map(\.number).contains(a) || !arrayB.map(\.number).contains(b) {
        throw SwitchError.error
    }
    //etc
}

func check(a: Int, b: Int) throws {
    if a < 0 || b < 0 || !arrayA.contains(where: { $0.number == a}) || !arrayB.contains(where: { $0.number == b }) {
        throw SwitchError.error
    }
    //etc
}
```

The first makes a new array of just the `number`s and checks it for the element -- the second checks without making the interim array. These are functionally the same, but may have different performance characteristics with larger arrays.

Comment: You're a God!!! Thank you very much my friend, and sorry for not clarifying the issue well from the beginning.